# Using DATEADD function to retrieve data created in past

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to query data in a table which has been created 11 days (or more) before today's date.

I tried using the below SQL query but it doesnt seem to work well for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM PRICE
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar,CREATED_AT, 112) > CONVERT(nvarchar,(DATEADD(DAY, -10, getdate())),112)
```

I have two records in this table that actually match my criteria.  (This is the original format of the CREATED_AT column in my table.)
2019-01-23 16:19:41.127
2019-01-04 15:21:41.127

But my query only picks the first one (Jan 23). What is it that I am doing wrong here?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Thanks

Comment: This date `2019-01-04 15:21:41.127` is more than 10 days old. How do you you expect your query to return it?

Comment: I need my query to return anything that is 11 days or older. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Why are you converting your dates to an `nvarchar`?

Comment: You mean more than 10 old, not the recent 10 days?

Comment: Yes, thats right. So today is Feb 2nd. I want my query to return all the orders that were created on or before Jan 22, and not between Jan 22 and today.

Comment: Your comparison operator `>` (which means "newer") should read `<` (which would mean "older"). Don't convert to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply function to the columns, if you can avoid it.  It can prevent the optimizer from making use of indexes and partitions.

Instead, you seem to want:

```
WHERE CREATED_AT < DATEADD(day, -10, getdate())
```

Or:

```
WHERE CREATED_AT < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -10, getdate()))
```

The first takes the time component into account.  The second removes the time component, so `created_at` has to be before midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Convert DATE data types to character data types to compare

Just use

```
SELECT * FROM PRICE WHERE CREATED_AT > DATEADD(DAY, -10, getdate())
```